Application of the Chain Rule in the Proof of Hadamard's Lemma
I read the proof for Hadamard's lemma available on Wikipedia but I do not understand the application of the chain rule in the proof.
In particular, $f$ is a smooth function defined on an open star-convex set $U$ of $n$-dimensional Euclidean space and $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$
The proof defines a function $h$ by:
$$h(t)=f(a+t(x-a))$$
for a fixed value of $x\in U$ and $0\leq t\leq 1$.
What I don't understand is the application of the chain rule
$$h'(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(a+t(x-a))(x_k-a_k).$$
This since I believe that the partial derivatives should not be taken with respect to the $x_k$, but with respect to the argumentes passed to $f$.
Formally, let $u_k(t)=a_k+t(x_k-a_k)$, then the chain rule states that:
$$h'(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_k}(a+t(x-a))\frac{d u_k}{d t}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_k}(a+t(x-a))(x_k-a_k).$$
At least that is what I believe and, by comparison, if we compute the partial derivative as stated in the proof of the lemma I get
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(a+t(x-a))=t\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_k}(a+t(x-a)).$$
Which is not the same thing.

$h’(t)=\sum_{k=1}^n(\partial_kf)(a+t(x-a))\cdot (x_k-a_k)$; when written this way, there is no confusion at all. Here, $\partial_kf$ means the $k^{th}$ partial derivative of the function $f$; see here for more on terminology and notation. This equality is a trivial consequence of the chain rule ($D(\phi\circ\psi)a=D\phi{\phi(a)}\circ D\psi_a$ in a special case… see the first part of my answer here). Also notation in more abstract situations.

The ‘mistake’ you’re making in your last line is you’re trying to compute the partials of the composite $x\mapsto f(a+t(x-a))$, but in fact the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(a+t(x-a))$ means by definition $(\partial_kf)(a+t(x-a))$, i.e a partial of $f$ evaluated at a weird point. If you want to write partials of the composite, you should write $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_k}\left(f(a+t(x-a))\right)$. The bracketing makes a difference as to the interpretation. Anyway, all this extra business with $x_k$ vs $u_k$ should be avoided on first pass through as I explain in my first link.
